# How to insert a component in a page without React?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension, where users would be able to chat with each other from the browser.

I want to divide the entire page into 2 parts (in a certain ratio) so that the right part will have a chat box and the left part will have the original page content.

I know that I have to manipulate the DOM at runtime by using createElement and appendChild in JS, but how do I insert a complex component which might have a lot of complicated logic inside it, with just plain old Javascript?

Right now, the component I want to add will be a chat box , which might use nodeJS socket.io to communicate with other people on other browsers.
Is there an easier way to accomplish this and not make dozens of createElement and appendChild calls?

Comment: what kind of component you want to add? A Webcomponent?

Comment: added in the question

Comment: Add it inside an iframe that points to an html file in your extension exposed in web_accessible_resources, [example](https://itnext.io/create-chrome-extension-with-reactjs-using-inject-page-strategy-137650de1f39).

Comment: I don't want to use React

Comment: That's just an example. You can use any other framework or do it manually. Look for examples of adding UI via web_accessible_resources.